# Magento2: Duplicate 2 tables in an overwritten method

Tags: magento2, overrides, column, duplicate

I'm overwriting a method to change the configuration of the table, the problem is that this column doubles it, magento adds the column of the overwritten file and the original file, if I delete the original file does not appear but is not a good solution.

Why it happens?

[image]

**Original file:**

```
namespace Mod\SapOnlineCrm\Block\Adminhtml\Docs;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{    
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Gsp\SapOnlineCrm\Framework\Data\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory $dataObjectFactory,
        \Gsp\SapOnlineCrm\Helper\DocsWS $docsWS,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->dataObjectFactory = $dataObjectFactory;
        $this->docsWS = $docsWS;
        $this->authSession = $authSession;

        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;

        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }       

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        if ($this->isOrder()) {
            $this->addColumn(
                'OrderStatus',
                [
                    'header' => __('Order status'),
                    'index' => 'OrderStatus',
                    'type' => 'options',
                    'options' => $this->getAttributeOptionsOrderStatuses()
                ]
            );
        }
        $this->addColumn(
            'DocNum',
            [
                'header' => __('Number'),
                'index' => 'DocNum',
                'type' => 'range'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'ExternalDocEntry',
            [
                'header' => __('Web Order'),
                'index' => 'ExternalDocEntry',
                'type' => 'range'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'CardCode',
            [
                'header' => __('Customer'),
                'index' => 'CardCode',
                'type' => 'text'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'CardName',
            [
                'header' => __('Name'),
                'index' => 'CardName',
                'type' => 'text'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'DocDate',
            [
                'header' => __('Date'),
                'index' => 'DocDate',
                'type' => 'date',
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'DocDueDate',
            [
                'header' => __('DueDate'),
                'index' => 'DocDueDate',
                'type' => 'date',
            ]
        );

        if ($this->getModaEnabled()) {
            $this->addColumn(
                'SeasonCode',
                [
                    'header' => __('Season'),
                    'index' => 'SeasonCode',
                    'type' => 'options',
                    'options' => $this->getAttributeOptionsSeasons()
                ]
            );
        }

        $this->addColumn(
            'DocTotal',
            [
                'header' => __('Amount'),
                'index' => 'DocTotal',
                'type' => 'range',
                'renderer' => '\Mod\SapOnlineCrm\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Currency',
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }    


    protected function getAttributeOptionsOrderStatuses()
    {
        return [
            '' => ' ',
            'O' => __('Opened'),
            'C' => __('Closed'),
            'E' => __('Orders partially delivered'),
            'EC' => __('Orders delivered completely'),
            'L' => __('Blocked orders'),
            'P' => __('Pending orders')
        ];
    }


}
```

**Intermediate file**

```
namespace Mod\SapOnlineCrm\Block\Adminhtml\Orders;

class Grid extends \Mod\SapOnlineCrm\Block\Adminhtml\Docs\Grid
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->type = parent::ORDERS;
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->_prepareData();
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

**Override file:**

```
namespace Mod\ShadFamilyProducts\Block\SapOnlineCrm\Adminhtml\Docs;

class Grid extends \Mod\SapOnlineCrm\Block\Adminhtml\Orders\Grid
{

    const PARAM_ORDERSTATUS = 'OrderStatusShad';

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        if ($this->isOrder()) {
            $this->addColumn(
                'OrderStatusShad',
                [
                    'header' => __('Order status'),
                    'index' => 'OrderStatusShad',
                    'type' => 'options',
                    'options' => $this->getAttributeOptionsOrderStatuses()
                ]
            );
        }
        $this->addColumn(
            'DocNum',
            [
                'header' => __('Document Number'),
                'index' => 'DocNum',
                'type' => 'range'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'ExternalDocEntry',
            [
                'header' => __('Web Order'),
                'index' => 'ExternalDocEntry',
                'type' => 'range'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'CardCode',
            [
                'header' => __('Customer'),
                'index' => 'CardCode',
                'type' => 'text'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'CardName',
            [
                'header' => __('Name'),
                'index' => 'CardName',
                'type' => 'text'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'DocDate',
            [
                'header' => __('Create Date'),
                'index' => 'DocDate',
                'type' => 'date',
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'DocDueDate',
            [
                'header' => __('Delivery Date'),
                'index' => 'DocDueDate',
                'type' => 'date',
            ]
        );

        if ($this->getModaEnabled()) {
            $this->addColumn(
                'SeasonCode',
                [
                    'header' => __('Season'),
                    'index' => 'SeasonCode',
                    'type' => 'options',
                    'options' => $this->getAttributeOptionsSeasons()
                ]
            );
        }

        $this->addColumn(
            'DocTotal',
            [
                'header' => __('Amount'),
                'index' => 'DocTotal',
                'type' => 'range',
                'renderer' => '\Mod\SapOnlineCrm\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Currency',
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    protected function getAttributeOptionsOrderStatuses()
    {
        return [
            '' => ' ',
            10 => __('Not confirmed'),
            22 => __('Locked'),
            33 => __('Confirmed'),
            44 => __('Picking list issued'),
            66 => __('Prepared'),
            70 => __('Order sent'),
            77 => __('Invoiced'),
            90 => __('Canceled')
        ];
    }

}
```

There are more columns but they do not come out duplicated.

Comment: Can you post the whole code you have written?

Comment: @SukumarGorai now I show it

Comment: @SukumarGorai Sorry, I was referring to the code, the column is still duplicated :(

Comment: Can you change this OrderStatusShad to OrderStatus?

Comment: @SukumarGorai that was the problem: D, I thought I could completely overwrite the method. I will have to inform myself.

Comment: Is it working now? As if you changed the name then magento identifies it as separate attribute or field.

Comment: Sure check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As if you changed the name then magento identifies it as separate attribute or field thats why its not working.

You need to use the below code:

```
if ($this->isOrder()) {
    $this->addColumn(
        'OrderStatus',
        [
            'header' => __('Order status'),
            'index' => 'OrderStatus',
            'type' => 'options',
            'options' => $this->getAttributeOptionsOrderStatuses()
        ]
    );
```

}

instead of yours

```
if ($this->isOrder()) {
    $this->addColumn(
        'OrderStatusShad',
        [
            'header' => __('Order status'),
            'index' => 'OrderStatusShad',
            'type' => 'options',
            'options' => $this->getAttributeOptionsOrderStatuses()
        ]
    );
}
```

Hope this helps!